# How can I use a DLL with JNA that does not have an interface

Tags: java, dll, jna

After spending a lot of time learning Python to implement a series of DLL based function into Java via Jython - I forgot to read Jython's documentation, and the lack of ctypes support rendered most of my code useless.

I didn't want to use JNI

I'm trying to access some functions from a [pcshll32.dll](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pcomhelp/v5r9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/emulator_programming08.htm), from Personal Communications using its HLLAPI.

I did manage to make it work with Python with almost no problems, it was really easy to find a lot of documentation and recipes on the web.

Now I discovered by accident the JNA, and I'm having a LOT of trouble with it. I can barely find information about it, specially when I'm trying to access non-standard DLLs.

From what I understand I need to write a pcshll32.class that will be the interface - much like the User32.class that seems to be an interface (or maybe I should call this a proxy...) to the User32.dll.

Well, that's what I think it's happening after reading [this](http://today.java.net/article/2009/11/11/simplify-native-code-access-jna).

So... How can I import an external DLL? Is it possible? Do I need to write the interface/proxy? Are there any samples out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
public interface PcShll32 extends StdCallLibrary { //StdCallLibrary is for Windows functions

    PcShll32 INSTANCE = (PcShll32) Native.loadLibrary(
                   "pcshll32", PcShll32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS); //Options are for Win32API

    // your methods
}
```

Of course you must provide this external library for JNA.

For me the best explanation is [the source code](http://download.java.net/general/jn_images/006/JNA-Article-Code.zip)

Comment: You can also use dynamic properties/functions in python to automagically map into a given native library.  See https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/DynamicallyTypedLanguages.md.